# Using vuex with typescript

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vuex

I am trying to use Typescript with a Vue project in which I use vuex for the data state management. In the [Vuex site](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/) it says:

> Note: for TypeScript users, vuex@3.0+ requires vue@2.5+, and vice versa.

However, there is no usage hint or specification around the site.

So, assuming we already have Vuex@3.0+ and Vue@2.5+, what is the thing to be done for Typescript implementation in the store member(s)? Should we have a separate file for types (i.e. `types.ts`) and store the data types as Typescript interfaces/classes there etc.?

P.S: The seamless usage of Typescript also with Vuex's [namespaced](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html#Namespacing) property would be perfectly nice.

Comment: I think you use it as normal but.. with types... So you just import your types from somewhere.

Comment: Indeed, I plan to make use a grpc backend -that was my motivation for adopting a 'typed' approach. So, yes, i just guessed i should use types for some grpc call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pull request by the vuex contributor ktsn points to the issue of integrating a close-to-full type safety in vuex. Its merge to the master branch should solve it:

https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/pull/1121